# How to set webform to show previous submissions to users?

Tags: webforms, users

I've got a webform I'm maintaining, and I'm not sure how to expose or suppress the "View Previous Submissions" link on a per=role basis. The previous submissions link is visible to the admin, but it's not visible to the user. I've looked at the role based permissions the webform settings but nothing looks obvious.

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I have the same behavior.

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to replicate the behavior from my dev machine, any thoughts on diagnosis?

Comment: Oh man...it's the "Access own webform submissions" permission setting : /

Comment: Of course it was!

Comment: Post it, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to confirm "Access own webform submissions" and "Edit own webform submissions" permission for the roles in question.